# angular 2 event listener on parent is not invoked from child-emitted event

Tags: angular

I set up my project using the [Angular 2 quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).  Then I have the following components, trying to follow a similar pattern [as here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent):

main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<menu (onToggleEvent)="onToggle($event)"></menu>`,
    directives: [ MenuComponent ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    onToggle(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

menu.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'menu',
    template: `<button (click)="toggleMe()">Toggle Me</button>`
})
export class MenuComponent {
    @Output onToggleEvent = new EventEmitter();

    public toggleMe(): void {
        this.onToggleEvent.emit('test');
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
        <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
        </script>
    </head>

    <!-- 3. Display the application -->
    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I debug, `toggleMe()` does execute and the event gets emitted, but the `onToggle()` method is never invoked.  Any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the bug - I didn't have parentheses next to the `@Output` annotation.  I was using the simple server included in the Angular QuickStart that uses BrowserSync and a TypeScript watcher to transpile on the fly.  Somehow adding just `@Output` instead of `@Output()` was never caught by the transpiler and this was silently failing.  After I stopped the server and attempted to restart it (which kicked off the transpilation), the error was thrown which clued me in to the bug.